# asp.net navigation menu style not correct when page loads

Tags: css, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an asp.net navigation menu on my page. 
When the page loads its style doesn't seem to be applied for a second. 
Then it become okay in a second. any solution for this issue ?

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" 
    EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal" 
    SkipLinkText="">

    <Items>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Main.aspx" Text="HOME" Value="PUBLIC-ITEM">
        </asp:MenuItem>
        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="ABOUT" Value="PUBLIC-ITEM">
        </asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>

    <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#9999FF" />
</asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your CSS style sheet towards the top of your HTML document. If it is not in a style sheet, make it so (and add it at the top). Your problem is caused by the page content loading before the styles are loaded.

Comment: its asp.net navigationMenu control... I think navigationMenu sets styles using javascript..

Comment: Same problem applies: if the JS code is loaded at the end of the page (common best practice) then it will be loaded after the nav menu elements, and therefore can't execute until after they're displayed. Either way the solution is to move your JS/CSS script references higher in the file, above the menu elements. (Note this of course will cause the user to wait for the JS to be downloaded before they see anything on the page.) In my ASP.NET applications the location of these is controlled by me in my templates using `@Scripts` and `@Styles` Razor directives (in both master and page templates).

Comment: I think there is no such editable script code for this control... Its autogenerated by the .net.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the control you're talking about. If you post an example I can maybe help but no guarantee. However I'm confident what I've given you gives you the root so you know where to look further. I've heard this problem is known as 'flash of unstyled content' if you want to Google further.

Comment: That's an older (at least different) form to what I'm used to. However I note your `StaticSelectedStyle` tag comes after the menu item elements. Put it above them. That would certainly fix the problem if this was regular HTML. I suspect it will help you here - assuming ASP.NET generates HTML as it parses your syntax line by line, this change will cause the style element to be emitted before the menu item elements. You can probably verify this by looking at the generated HTML source of your final page and seeing where/how the styles are being applied to the menu.

Comment: Sorry that's all I got for you.